# Multiple choice in calendar doesn't work - primeNG

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I want to use calendar in primeNG - range and multiple options, but it doesn't work. I can only choose one date from calendar.

```
<div class="box-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p-calendar maxDateCount="2" placeholder="Choose days" [(ngModel)]="dates" selectionMode="multiple" readonlyInput="true"></p-calendar>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p-calendar placeholder="Choose range of date" [(ngModel)]="rangeDates" selectionMode="range" readonlyInput="true" ></p-calendar>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Component.ts

```
import { MultiSelectModule, CalendarModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class CalendarDemo {

dates: Date[];
rangeDates: Date[];

}
```

Comment: **check the tags you want to apply before you apply them** you have errors in them

Comment: why do you import modules in a component?

Comment: I import in "module.ts" file. The above I have mistaken.

Comment: Please correct your tags

Comment: It is not problem with tags. Look at my comment below solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a [working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/L8dS9KBvW3CInu65KRfz?p=preview) to demonstrate it should work. It is also working on the [PrimeNG demo page](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar), so it has probably something to do with external implementation details of your application.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.template.html'
})

export class AppComponent {
    dates: Date[];
    rangeDates: Date[];
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';

// Import PrimeNG modules
import { CalendarModule } from 'primeng';

@NgModule({ 
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, FormsModule, CalendarModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

app.template.html

```
<h3>Angular 4.2.6, PrimeNG 4.1.3, Calendar example</h3>

<!--<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="value" [inline]="true"></p-calendar>-->

<div class="box-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p-calendar maxDateCount="2" placeholder="Choose days" [(ngModel)]="dates" selectionMode="multiple" readonlyInput="true"></p-calendar>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p-calendar placeholder="Choose range of date" [(ngModel)]="rangeDates" selectionMode="range" readonlyInput="true" ></p-calendar>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Problem solved: I have 4.0.0 version of primeNG, must be - 4.1.3.